# Apples SinglePing app doesn't call delegate methods

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, ping

I am trying [SimplePing app from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SimplePing/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000716-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2). But delegate methods aren't called. I am trying to find solution, but I am also asking here for help.

Thank you.

Here is complete MainViewController class to look at.

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UITableViewController, SimplePingDelegate {

    let hostName = "www.apple.com"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = self.hostName
    }

    var pinger: SimplePing?
    var sendTimer: Timer?

    func start(forceIPv4: Bool, forceIPv6: Bool) {
        self.pingerWillStart()

        NSLog("start")

        let pinger = SimplePing(hostName: self.hostName)
        self.pinger = pinger

        if (forceIPv4 && !forceIPv6) {
            pinger.addressStyle = .icmPv4
        } else if (forceIPv6 && !forceIPv4) {
            pinger.addressStyle = .icmPv6
        }

        pinger.delegate = self
        pinger.start()
    }

    func stop() {
        NSLog("stop")
        self.pinger?.stop()
        self.pinger = nil

        self.sendTimer?.invalidate()
        self.sendTimer = nil

        self.pingerDidStop()
    }

    func sendPing() {
        self.pinger!.send(with: nil)
    }

    // MARK: pinger delegate callback

    private func simplePing(pinger: SimplePing, didStartWithAddress address: NSData) {
        NSLog("pinging %@", MainViewController.displayAddressForAddress(address: address))

        self.sendPing()

        assert(self.sendTimer == nil)
        self.sendTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(MainViewController.sendPing), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    private func simplePing(pinger: SimplePing, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        NSLog("failed: %@", MainViewController.shortErrorFromError(error: error))

        self.stop()
    }

    private func simplePing(pinger: SimplePing, didSendPacket packet: NSData, sequenceNumber: UInt16) {
        NSLog("#%u sent", sequenceNumber)
    }

    private func simplePing(pinger: SimplePing, didFailToSendPacket packet: NSData, sequenceNumber: UInt16, error: NSError) {
        NSLog("#%u send failed: %@", sequenceNumber, MainViewController.shortErrorFromError(error: error))
    }

    private func simplePing(pinger: SimplePing, didReceivePingResponsePacket packet: NSData, sequenceNumber: UInt16) {
        NSLog("#%u received, size=%zu", sequenceNumber, packet.length)
    }

    private func simplePing(pinger: SimplePing, didReceiveUnexpectedPacket packet: NSData) {
        NSLog("unexpected packet, size=%zu", packet.length)
    }

    // MARK: utilities

    static func displayAddressForAddress(address: NSData) -> String {
        var hostStr = [Int8](repeating: 0, count: Int(NI_MAXHOST))

        let success = getnameinfo(
            address.bytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: sockaddr.self),
            //UnsafePointer(address.bytes),
            socklen_t(address.length), 
            &hostStr, 
            socklen_t(hostStr.count), 
            nil, 
            0, 
            NI_NUMERICHOST
        ) == 0
        let result: String
        if success {
            result = String(cString: hostStr)
        } else {
            result = "?"
        }
        return result
    }

    /// Returns a short error string for the supplied error.
    ///
    /// - parameter error: The error to render.
    ///
    /// - returns: A short string representing that error.

    static func shortErrorFromError(error: NSError) -> String {
        if error.domain == kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork as String && error.code == Int(CFNetworkErrors.cfHostErrorUnknown.rawValue) {
            if let failureObj = error.userInfo[kCFGetAddrInfoFailureKey] {
                if let failureNum = failureObj as? NSNumber {
                    if failureNum.intValue != 0 {
                        let f = gai_strerror(Int32(failureNum.intValue))
                        if f != nil {
                            return String(cString: f!)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if let result = error.localizedFailureReason {
            return result
        }
        return error.localizedDescription
    }

    // MARK: table view delegate callback

    @IBOutlet var forceIPv4Cell: UITableViewCell!
    @IBOutlet var forceIPv6Cell: UITableViewCell!
    @IBOutlet var startStopCell: UITableViewCell!

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath)!
        switch cell {
        case forceIPv4Cell, forceIPv6Cell:
            cell.accessoryType = cell.accessoryType == .none ? .checkmark : .none
        case startStopCell:
            if self.pinger == nil {
                let forceIPv4 = self.forceIPv4Cell.accessoryType != .none
                let forceIPv6 = self.forceIPv6Cell.accessoryType != .none
                self.start(forceIPv4: forceIPv4, forceIPv6: forceIPv6)
            } else {
                self.stop()
            }
        default:
            fatalError()
        }
        self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)
    }

    func pingerWillStart() {
        self.startStopCell.textLabel!.text = "Stop…"
    }

    func pingerDidStop() {
        self.startStopCell.textLabel!.text = "Start…"
    }
}
```

I've converted it to Swift 4 syntax, but nothing works on Simulator or real device. I tap on IPv4 or IPv6 and then start, but nothing happens.

Comment: Did you copy the file from apple or did you type it yourself? The app from apple looks fine to me and should work.

Comment: I copy it from Apple and converted to Swift 4 some methods, but everything is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the project from Apple and tried it myself. You probably have the wrong method signature for the didSelect event of the table view.

Make sure to change
`override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`
 to
`override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`
inside the MainViewController.swift.

I hope this fixes your issue.

Edit: You also need to change the signature of all delegate methods in your MainViewController.swift. For example `func simplePing(pinger: SimplePing, didFailWithError error: NSError)` should become `func simplePing(_ pinger: SimplePing, didFailWithError error: Error)`.

Comment: Yes, I did that. But everytime I select IPv4 and tap to start, nothing happens. Delegate methods aren't triggered. Delegate is assigned, so I am a little confused about that.

Comment: @petesalt Weird, it's working for me. Did you also fix the method signatures for the delegate methods inside the `MainViewController`?

Comment: Pascal_AC, yes. But nothing works. On Simulator and real device. Nothing.

Comment: @petesalt Could you add your MainViewController.swift to your question?

Comment: OK, here it is, look at original question.

Comment: @petesalt The method signatures of the delegate methods are wrong. I've edited my answer with one change as example. I don't want to put all signature changes there but you can easily find the others with the help of code completion in Xcode.